# generating a schema for random id

Tags: graphql, schema, resolver

I have the following object:

```
tabs: {
             <id>: {  // this id will be a dinamic id and everytime it will contain UUID
                  title: "",         
                  body: ""
             }   
         }
```

I'm wondering how ro generate a schema for this random ID one and resolver, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

These days I was studying something similar.

I adapted some code from my studies. Let me know if this helps.

````
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const { generate } = require("shortid");

const typeDefs = `
    type Tab {
        id: ID!
        title: String!
        body: String!
    }
    type Query {
        allTabs: [Tab!]!
    }
    type Mutation {
        addTab(title: String! body: String!): Tab
    }
`;

let tabs = [
  {
    id: "2WEKaVNO",
    title: "Title 1",
    body: "Body 1"
  }
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allTabs: () => tabs
  },
  Mutation: {
    addTab: (parent, { title, body }) => {
      let newTab = {
        id: generate(),
        title, 
        body
      };

      tabs = [...tabs, newTab];

      return newTab;
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server
  .listen()
  .then(({ url }) => `GraphQL server listening on ${url}`)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);```
````